# Laravel 5.2: How to autofill the creation date of the form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling with a question that i'm asking myself. I have a form in laravel that posts a new row with data on the index file. Right now I have a couple of set values that I insert into the database. One of those values is "date", I am asking myself: How can I from the moment that I press on the 'save' button automatically fill the created_at field in my database.

Would love to get some help with this

Comment: As far as i know laravels timestamps (created_at, updated_at) are automatically filled when updating or creating records. But if you use Model::insert() then they wont be automatically filled. Only if you use fillable eg. Model::create(data);

Comment: Add this line in your migration $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` for `created_at` field inside your controller (or where you save your obj)

Or use laravel timestamps. It wil auto stamp the date of update and creation

Edit: like our Dutch friend mentioned. just use date

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). No need for carbon.

Comment: This answered my question. thanks for the info. I can only accept this answer as the correct one in around 5 minutes (-:

Comment: Dutchies United